# Графики Plotly в Jupyter Notebook после загрузки блокнота не отображаются

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly

Я использую Plotly для визуализации результатов вычислений. После сохранения своей работы в блокноте и загрузки ее в следующей сессии, графики не отображаются. Приходится запускать вычисления заново, что весьма неудобно. Есть ли решение для сохранения графиков в блокноте, чтобы при загрузке новой сессии  не производить вычисления заново. Matplotlib сохраняет результат работы, но не обладает интерактивностью.

Comment: Есть ли у вас в блокноте вызов “%matplotlib …” и если есть то с каким параметром (backend)?

Comment: Вы сохраняете результаты работы скрипта в html в явном виде? что-то типа `fig.write_html("path/to/file.html")`? Если да, то графики в этом html будут сохраняться.

Comment: Когда пользуюсь  Matplotlib, то никакого вызова я не делаю. А вот результаты работы скрипта я явно не сохраняю.  Спасибо за направление поиска относительно fig.write_html.

Comment: Спасибо, fig.write_html(file) в первом графике решил проблему. Сейчас при загрузке сессии графики подгружаются, интерактивность на графиках есть.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо, fig.write_html(file) в первом графике решил проблему. Сейчас при загрузке сессии графики подгружаются, интерактивность на графиках есть

Answer (score 0):

Еще один способ оставить графики "живыми" после перезагрузки - это изменить рендер в самом блокноте, прописав `fig.show("notebook")` вместо обычного `fig.show()`.
Если это не помогло, то вам следует прописать следующий код в начале ноутбука:

```
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default='notebook'
```

Ну и также следует убедиться, что ноутбук - доверенный.